# GridView MasterDetail - The detail can be of different types

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, master-detail

I want a GridView Master-Detail.

The type of the entity in the Detail can be of different types (always the same type per Master and those types inherited from the same base class)

In the Detail, I want to have Properties from the BaseClass and also from the derived class, so the Detail on one Master can have different number of rows that the Detail of another Master.

I'd like to avoid generating the columns on the codeBehind

I have tried with different details ans selecting one by using embedded code but I can't combine with DataBinding Expressions

```
<% if(Eval("Type").ToString() == "Type1") { %
    CodeOfDetailType1
<% }%>
<% if(Eval("Type").ToString() == "Type2") { %
    CodeOfDetailType2
<% }%>
```

...

I have tried also saving the discriminator in a HiddenField (OK). And then in the embedded code tried to access that value, but I don't know hoy to access it

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using strongly typed GridView. Lets say you have the following classes

```
public class MasterClass
{
    public SubClass1 subClass1 { get; set; }
    public SubClass2 subClass2 { get; set; }
}

public class SubClass1
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class SubClass2
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a List of of `MasterClass` and bind it to the GridView

```
List<MasterClass> list = new List<MasterClass>();
list.Add(new MasterClass() { subClass1 = new SubClass1() { id = 1, name = "Name 1" } });
list.Add(new MasterClass() { subClass2 = new SubClass2() { ID = 2, NAME = "Name 2" } });

GridView1.DataSource = list;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

In the GridView add the `ItemType` with the full NameSpace. Now you can easily access the properties.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ItemType="YourNameSpace.MasterClass">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

                <%# Item.subClass1 != null ? Item.subClass1.id : Item.subClass2.ID %>
                <%# Item.subClass1 != null ? Item.subClass1.name : Item.subClass2.NAME %>     

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: That's not inheritance.
Also, the number and types of the properties from the derived classes are completely different

Comment: @popiandro. It is just an easy example of how you can use a strongly typed GridView.